# How do I use a variable in Flutter that doesn't exist until the application has run?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with user authentication and I need a way to run a PKCE generator and then insert that output value in a url, however on my log in page it tells me that the PKCE code variable is undefined. I would really appreciate some advice, I know that I must be doing something wrong.

The PKCE generator function:

```
const String _charset =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~';

String createCodeChallenge() {
  final codeChallenge = List.generate(
      128, (i) => _charset[Random.secure().nextInt(_charset.length)]).join();
  print('Code challenge: $codeChallenge');
  return codeChallenge;
}
```

My home page calling the function:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  createCodeChallenge();
  
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      //home: LoginPage(), Login page for later
      home: LogInPage(),
      //home: PostsPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

My attempt at using the variable on my log in page:

```
class LogInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LogInPage({super.key}); 
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Log in"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Log in"),
          onPressed: () {
            launchUrl(
               Uri.parse('https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d0bc225b046cdf15a2fb29f7d36c513c&code_challenge=$codeChallenge&state=RequestID34'),
                mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
          
          },
```

I've tried directly using the function in the log in page, I've tried 'getting' myn function variable, nothing sees to be working.

Comment: If this is standard PKCE, then the code challenge isn't just a random value. It's the base64 encoding of SHA-256 hash of the verifier (which is random). You'll need to generate a random value for that and hold onto it. You'll need that original value later when you get the token. (Regarding your undefined variable, you'll probably need to import the other source file. Further note that your variable `codeChallenge` is just local to that method - you don't store the returned value anywhere. And, as above, that's no the value you need to be storing - store the original verifier value.)

Comment: Recommendations are totally off topic in SO, but there's a package that does the work of OIDC for you... ( https://pub.dev/packages/oidc )

Answer (score 0):

If this is standard PKCE, then the code challenge isn't just a random value. It's the base64 encoding of SHA-256 hash of the verifier (which is random). You'll need to generate a random value for that and hold onto it. You'll need that original value later when you get the token.

To generate the verifier and code challenge, use code similar to this:

```
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart'; // you need this import at the top of the file

  final verifier = _random64(Random.secure()); // hold onto this value for later

  final hash = SHA256Digest().process(ascii.encode(verifier));
  final challenge = base64Url.encode(hash).replaceAll('=', '');
  // use challenge in the URL, then throw it away
```

where `_random64` is defined as:

```
String _random64(Random r) {
  // generate a random string in URL-safe base64
  final raw = Uint8List.fromList(
    List<int>.generate(32, (_) => r.nextInt(256)),
  );
  return base64Url.encode(raw).replaceAll('=', '');
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't generating a SHA-256 hash value, it is being able to access that value. I have the function import in the file where I need it but it still says that the variable name is undefined.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, your `codeChallenge` variable is local. See a tutorial like https://www.scaler.com/topics/flutter-tutorial/variables-in-dart/ (There's even an example in the section 'local variables' that shows why you cannot access local variables from outside of their scope.)